# Different pander performance between .Rmd and .Rnw

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pander

I'm having some trouble getting pander to work the same way in a .Rnw file as it does in my .Rmd file.  In both, I'm using knitr to weave the pdf.  My .Rmd file looks like

````
---
title: "My title"
output: pdf_document
---
```{r}
library(pander)
panderOptions('big.mark', ',')
panderOptions('table.style','rmarkdown')
panderOptions('table.alignment.default','right')
panderOptions('table.alignment.rownames','left')
panderOptions('digits','10')
df <- data.frame('a' = 1:3, 'b' = 4:6, 'c' = 7:9)
pander(df)
```
````

The dataframe looks really nice in the output as it converts the dashed lines into solid ones.  However when I try to do something similar in my .Rnw file, everything is printed as if it were a sentence rather than a table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<model_data>>=
library(pander)
panderOptions('big.mark', ',')
panderOptions('table.style','rmarkdown')
panderOptions('table.alignment.default','right')
panderOptions('table.alignment.rownames','left')
panderOptions('digits','10')
df <- data.frame('a' = 1:3, 'b' = 4:6, 'c' = 7:9)
pander(df)
@
\end{document}
```

This looks terrible, I can call pandoc.table(df) instead and then its printed in a table format at least but it has the dashed lines unlike when its printed in the .Rmd file.  How to I get it to print exactly like it does in the .Rmd file but inside of an .Rnw file?

Comment: The first file is markdown, which can be converted to PDF/HTML/docx/whatever, while the latter is a `tex` file, which can be only compiled into PDF. To keep it short, as `pander` turns R objects into `markdown` (and not `tex`), you should use it with `Rmd` files, but not `Rnw`. For direct `tex` output, see e.g. `xtable`.